# Can we control IOS smart banner display?

Tags: html, iphone, ios6, smartbanner

IOS6+ for Iphones implement smart banner feature. This is simply adding a meta tag that includes an appstore Id.

1. Is it possible to show this smart banner more than once? Can we control its frequency? Suppose If I want to show it every once in a week, Is this possible?
2. I don't see smart banner in chrome browser in IOS6+ when implemented using above tag? Is there any other way to implement this in chrome.

I didn't see any documentation related to these issues.

Answer (score 1):

CKR,

Official documentation is [minimal](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html).

I would recommend using a plugin such as the [jQuery Smartbanner](http://www.jasny.net/jquery.smartbanner/). However; this also isn't a perfect solution. I am currently trying to find a way to disable the native banner from displaying in mobile Safari, as the plugin generates its own markup, thus displaying two banners at the same time.

Just to clarify: it appears that there is no way to control the native banner. From the documentation:

"[Users] will appreciate that banners are presented unobtrusively at the top of a webpage, instead of as a full-screen ad interrupting the web content. And with a large and prominent close button, a banner is easy for users to dismiss. When the user returns to the webpage, the banner won’t reappear."

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a custom Smart Banner for iOS and Android is easy.

You only need a couple of meta tags and 13.2 KB of JavaScript library, see  https://github.com/ain/smartbanner.js/#basic-usage for instructions.